# Can someone explain this Objective C @property syntax?

Tags: objective-c-2.0

Reading over some example Objective C code just now.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *descriptionLabel;
```

I understand that here we're declaring a property named descriptionLabel. The property has two attributes: nonatomic and strong.

What I don't understand is there are two type definitions `... IBOutlet UILabel ...`

Can anyone explain why and what the implications are of two type definitions?

Comment: I think IBOutlet is #define'd to be a "empty". This is basically used as an indicator by Interface builder to indicate properties that can be set.

Comment: Thanks for answering - would you like to re-post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBOutlet is #define'd to be a "empty". This is basically used as an indicator by Interface builder to indicate properties that can be set.

Answer (score 1):

Please read about [IBOutlet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW3) and [IBAction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW32) in the [*Cocoa Fundamentals Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH1-SW1).